# Multiple record sources for a report

Tags: ms-access

In Access 2013, I have 4 different queries that ultimately need to be tied to one report. Each query need to be used when a value in a combo box located on a form is anything other than "*" (there are 4 different combo boxes, one for each query).  I wonder if it's possible to use a variation of If statement to let Access know which query I need it to use based on the value in each of those 4 combo boxes.

For example:
IF [Forms]![Report Console]![cbo1]<>"*" (isn't blank) then use Query1 as a record source for the report, IF [Forms]![Report Console]![cbo2]<>"*" then use Query2 as a record source, etc.
Is it at all possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the report's `RecordSource` in its `On Open` event.

```vb
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If Nz([Forms]![Report Console]![cbo1], "") <> "" Then
        Me.RecordSource = "Query1"
    ElseIf Nz([Forms]![Report Console]![cbo2], "") <> "" Then
        Me.RecordSource = "Query2"
    ' etc
    End If

End Sub
```

Of course all queries must return the same set of columns.